# Laravel Storage Framework and Log File/Folder Permissions Issue

Tags: php, laravel, permissions, webserver

I'm having an issue with Laravel's file/folder permissions when they are generated from different sources. This may be a bit long winded, but bear with me.

**Scenario**

1) An `artisan` command, called `TestCommand.php`, triggered via `php artisan test:command` has the following code:

```
public function handle(){
  \Log::info("Test Command Executed from Command Line");
}
```

2) A Contoller Function in `TestController.php`, triggered when accessing `http://localhost/test`, which has the following code:

```
public function test(){
  \Log::info("Test Command Executed from Web View");
}
```

Both functions work correctly when triggered individually, **but as soon as one is triggered, the other will not work,** as the generated log file in `storage/logs` now has incorrect permissions, user and/or group.

**Situation 1**

If I run `php artisan test:command`, I get the following log file:

```
-rw-r--r-- | 1 | tim | wheel | 76B | 25 Aug 14:03 | laravel-2017-08-25.log
```

And navigating to `http://localhost/test` returns the following error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

No Laravel stack trace ("Woops, something went wrong") is displayed, as that only happens following writing to the Laravel logs.

**Situation 2**

If I navigate to `http://localhost/test` first, I get this log file:

```
-rw-r--r-- | 1 | _www | wheel | 72B | 25 Aug 14:06 | laravel-2017-08-25.log
```

And running the `php artisan test:command` returns the following:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file ".../storage/logs/laravel-2017-08-25.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in .../vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:97
>   Stack trace: ...

**Conclusion**

Notice the user is now `_www` instead of `tim`, which is to be expected given the generation source of the file in `storage/logs`. Retroactively, this can be fixed quite easily by running:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/logs
```

But that's not a good solution for a number of reasons:

- 777 is a bad idea for production web servers, and 755 doesn't seem to work for my configuration.
- Any time a new file is created (daily for logs, any time for files in `storage/framework/*`, etc) this command would need to be run again.
- I don't have direct access to the webserver where this command would have to be run x number of times per day, meaning I would have to bug someone else to do it.

Given all this, how do I unify the files to allow either source to create the file and then modify the file as needed?

Webserver is apache, dev environment is Mac, production is linux

**Update**

I think a good solution is to have `tim` and `_www` in the same group, and assign `storage/logs` to that group using

```
chgrp -R <user_group> storage
```

But then the next issue is that by default, the permissions on any generated folder in Laravel is `644`, which doesn't allow write access by the `group`, only read.

Will look into modifying this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to this issue; ACLs!

On Mac, there's an option for `chmod +a ...`, which will add default directory permissions to whatever folder you specify. In my case, I want to use ACLs that allow `tim` and `_www` full access to files/folders under `storage`, since they'll both be accessing/writing to it constantly:

```
chmod -R +a 'tim allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' storage
chmod -R +a '_www allow read,write,delete,add_file,add_subdirectory,file_inherit,directory_inherit' storage
```

Applying this recursively allows ACLs to be set on any folders generated by Laravel in the storage directory, most important being those is `storage/framework/cache`.

On Linux, ACLs seem to be slightly different, but the idea is the same:

```
chmod g+s storage
setfacl -R -d -m u::rwx storage
setfacl -R -d -m g::rx storage
setfacl -R -d -m o::rx storage
```

This would effectively set the file permissions to storage (and all subfolders) to `755`, which seems to be what my configuration needs to allow writing properly.